# How to change the modalPresentationStyle when the modal view controller is already shown?

Tags: ios

I want to set my `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` style modal view to become `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` style sometime,but when it's already shown with `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` style,it can't goto fullscreen using code"`[xx setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];`"

Is there a way to change the present style after a modal view shown? My code like this:

```
UITableDownload* vc = [[UITableDownload alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[nav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[MainAppDelegate mainBrowserViewController] presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

...//after shown,sometime I implement following code:
[nav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];//(The "nav" object is the same as above code)
//But the change style code takes no effect.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is still a question for me in an iOS 7 app and at this point I'm left to conclude that changing the modalPresentationStyle after the transition has occurred just has no effect.

Comment: agreed still today

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer or not, but have you tried accessing the controller via the modalViewController?

Something like:

```
[self.modalViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
```

rather than the:

```
[nav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
```

Comment: this will have no effect whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try to change `modalpresentationStyle` as `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`

```
[nav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];
```

This type should autorotate your modal view